# Calling REST API from JavaScript with Firefox is not working

Tags: javascript, api, firefox, rest

I'm using the following code to make a call to a REST API using JavaScript. This code works fine with IE but hangs at send method with Firefox 9.0.1. I believe IE is *not* cashing the previous response.

I have tried debugging with Firebug, but it's not helping. XMLHttpRequest object, which is for Firefox, is created successfully and it goes through all the code, but no response.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function processRequest() {
         var signedURI = "http://api.saaspose.com/v1.0/storage/disc?appSID=myappSID&signature=mySignature";

        var xmlhttp = null;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            if (typeof xmlhttp.overrideMimeType != 'undefined') {
                xmlhttp.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
            }
        } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } else {
            alert('Not supported!');
        }

        xmlhttp.open('GET', signedURI, true);

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

            alert(xmlhttp.responseText);

            } else {
                //alert("ready state : " + xmlhttp.readyState.toString() + " status : " + xmlhttp.status.toString());
            }
        };

         xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
</script>
```

Any idea why is this issue occurring with Firefox but not with IE?

Comment: What version of Firefox? Also, do you have Firebug installed? Can you see what's happening over the wire?

Comment: are you debugging with firebug? very handy at times like these.

Comment: The FF version is 9.0.1. I'll try with Firebug and share the results with you guys. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I have tried debugging with Firebug, but it's not helping. XMLHttpRequest object, which is for Firefox, is created successfully and it goes through all the code, but no response. The URI and code is working fine with IE.

Comment: Are you certain that IE has just not cached a previous response? As it's a `GET` request IE will cache the response. This would mean it appeared to work but actually had not.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that's not the IE cashing the previous response. Even if it was so, at least IE got the first response, but FF didn't :)

Comment: Is this a cross-site request?  If so, is the `api.saaspose.com` site sending the right CORS headers?

Comment: The point is: why is it working for IE, but not for FF? If it is having issues due to cross-site request why not with IE too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The team had to resolve this issue by adding JSONP support to the WCF services and then using the jQuery at the client end like this:

```
        $(function () {
        $("#disc").click(function () {
            $.getJSON("http://api.saaspose.com/v1.0/storage/disc?appSID=appsid&signature=signature&callback=?", function (data) {
                var items = [];
                $("#discResult").append('<br/><b>Status: ' + data.Status + '</b>');
                if (data.Status = 'OK') {
                    var discUsage = data.DiscUsage;
                    $.each(discUsage, function (key, val) {
                        items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + key + ': ' + val + '</li>');
                    });

                    $('<ul/>', {
                        'class': 'my-new-list',
                        html: items.join('')
                    }).appendTo('#discResult');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Thank you all for your comments.